# Windows 7 Boot Loader -- modify boot options while booting?

Tags: windows-7, windows, bootloader, bootmgr

While booting with the Windows 7 Boot Manager, I have, by accident, triggered a screen which allows me to edit the boot command line, before the OS boots (similar to how GRUB allows you to press <kbd>E</kbd> and then modify the parameters on the fly).

I don't remember the key combination for this, though... or whether or not I needed to change any particular setting.

Does anyone know how to bring up this screen while booting?

Comment: F8 maybe? Then one of the options from there

Comment: @JourneymanGeek: No, I mean the screen that lets you *type* in the command line options (like in GRUB), not the old option selection screen that has been there for more than a decade. :P

Comment: There _is no command line_ until after Microsoft's Boot Manager has ceded control.  The command line passed to the Windows NT kernel is constructed by `winload`, the kernel loader, in its `AhCreateLoadOptionsString` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah... it's the <kbd>F10</kbd> key, and it only works for certain (Windows?) boot options.